# How to install driver for Linksys ae6000 wireless usb adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

I am very new to linux and don't quite understand how to install/update anything via the command line. I am running 64 bit ubuntu 14.04 and have connected to the internet only when using the Ethernet cable. I have researched somewhat on what I need to do to install the WiFi USB adapter for linksys ae6000 but unfortunately I am very lost in the whole process. Do I need to build the driver and if so where do I start?

Comment: If you unplug and reseat the adapter does the computer recognize it and does it work properly?

Answer (score 3):

Steps:

1. Unplug WiFi dongle from USB
2. Update your sources and upgrade if any:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update 
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
3. Install GNU compiler collection:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential
   ```
4. Install git:

   sudo apt-get install git
5. Get sources:

   ```
   git clone https://sanrath@bitbucket.org/sanrath/mediatek_mt7610u_sta_driver_linux-64bit.git
   ```
6. Build driver:

   ```
   cd mediatek_mt7610u_sta_driver_linux-64bit
   make clean
   make 
   sudo make install
   ```
7. After the last command connect your USB WiFi adapter to any USB port.
8. If you still can't see it:

   ```
   sudo ifconfig ra0 up
   sudo service network-manager restart
   ```

Then you should have it working and seeing the wireless networks.

[Thanks to pintu for making this possible](http://hprath.com/2014/06/cisco-linksys-ae6000-ac580-media-tek-mt7610u-mt7630u-mt7650u-linux-x64-driver-patch/)