# Linksys ae6000 wireless usb adapter don't work

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

Hello I'm one day new at this. Installed Lubuntu, wired network works fine. then I passed the rest of my day read and try nearly everything on every site possible. Clearly I need help.

My old laptop is an Asus Z7100 and of course wifi usb linksys AE6000 which was working well on windows 7.

here the step I've followed from here

[How to install driver for Linksys ae6000 wireless usb adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716656/how-to-install-driver-for-linksys-ae6000-wireless-usb-adapter)

Still can't see it or any network available and my dongle led is not on.

if I do `sudo ifconfig ra0 up*`

There I end up with  **No such device**

But if I do:

`lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 13b1:003e Linksys AE6000 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [MediaTek MT7610U]
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Cisco never released a linux Driver for this Dongle USB.

Thankfully, some folks worked on drivers themselves and published them. You will have to compile and install the driver for yourself. I use a fork (Viish) of the ones from xtknight (https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes) which I hope will get merged soon.

I suppose you have git installed and can access internet somehow (e.g. Cable network, or your cellphone through USB using Thethering). Unplug the USB key, open your terminal and enter the following commands one by one (some require your sudo password):

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)    
git clone https://github.com/Viish/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes.git
cd mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Then restart your system with your USB key connected. If nothing happens, open a terminal again and use:

```
sudo ifconfig ra0 up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Kernel 4.19 already has the correct drivers. Plug & Play. I used xanmod, but you guys are free to choose your own. no Led Light though. Weird, but work.